# restsharp WP7 JSON datetime format serialization

Tags: restsharp

The restsharp docs say that the JsonSerializer supports the ISO and Javascript Date Objects JSON date styles by default. In my WP7 app it is defaulting to the ISO style, how can I tell it to use the Javascript Date Objects style instead? I don't see, and can't find, an obvious answer. Thanks!